# submit 2 form 1 submit symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, submit

I have two forms in my twig file for 2 different entities (entity1, entity2)

```
{{form_start(form1)}}
{{form_end(form1)}}

{{form_start(form2)}}
{{form_end(form2)}}
```

In my controller the form1 submit work and it returns me some data but it doesn't save the entity data to database... I want to do it from the second submit.

```
if ($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isvalid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity1);
        $em->flush();

        $entity2->setIdentity1(entity1);
        $em->persist($entity2);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

I try with that code but it doesn't work. Data of form1 are all null.  var_dump(form1).

Is it possible to do that or must I put all in one form?